# How do I change the following SVG code from letter 'B' to 'A'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

The following code represents the SVG image attached below, how do I change the letter 'B' to 'A' without disturbing any other properties in there.

```
import React from 'react';

const IconLoader = () => (
  <svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <title>Loader Logo</title>
    <g>
      <g id="B" transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
        <path
          d="M45.691667,45.15 C48.591667,46.1 50.691667,48.95 50.691667,52.2 C50.691667,57.95 46.691667,61 40.291667,61 L28.541667,61 L28.541667,30.3 L39.291667,30.3 C45.691667,30.3 49.691667,33.15 49.691667,38.65 C49.691667,41.95 47.941667,44.35 45.691667,45.15 Z M33.591667,43.2 L39.241667,43.2 C42.791667,43.2 44.691667,41.85 44.691667,38.95 C44.691667,36.05 42.791667,34.8 39.241667,34.8 L33.591667,34.8 L33.591667,43.2 Z M33.591667,47.5 L33.591667,56.5 L40.191667,56.5 C43.691667,56.5 45.591667,54.75 45.591667,52 C45.591667,49.2 43.691667,47.5 40.191667,47.5 L33.591667,47.5 Z"
          fill="currentColor"
        />
      </g>
      <path
        stroke="currentColor"
        strokeWidth="5"
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        d="M 50, 5
                  L 11, 27
                  L 11, 72
                  L 50, 95
                  L 89, 73
                  L 89, 28 z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
);

export default IconLoader;
```

[image: SVG of the following Code]

After Changing the value of d in the code, I Ended up with this
[image]

How do I center the element to resolve this?

Comment: Change the path's d attribute so it draws something else. If you don't know how, use an SVG editor such as inkscape to do it graphically.

Comment: Ditch React (for the time being) Copy the SVG to CodePen, JSFiddle or your IDE (if you have an SVG preview plugin) so you can edit and learn what ``d="M45.691667,45.15 C48.591667...`` is and does... (I did the same years ago; and never used React again  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change is pretty simple since the svg file appears well documented. All you need to do is change the `d` path info for the following lines.

```
<g id="B" transform="translate(11.000000, 5.000000)">
    <path
        d="M45.691667,45.15 C48.591667,46.1 50.691667,48.95 50.691667,52.2 C50.691667,57.95 46.691667,61 40.291667,61 L28.541667,61 L28.541667,30.3 L39.291667,30.3 C45.691667,30.3 49.691667,33.15 49.691667,38.65 C49.691667,41.95 47.941667,44.35 45.691667,45.15 Z M33.591667,43.2 L39.241667,43.2 C42.791667,43.2 44.691667,41.85 44.691667,38.95 C44.691667,36.05 42.791667,34.8 39.241667,34.8 L33.591667,34.8 L33.591667,43.2 Z M33.591667,47.5 L33.591667,56.5 L40.191667,56.5 C43.691667,56.5 45.591667,54.75 45.591667,52 C45.591667,49.2 43.691667,47.5 40.191667,47.5 L33.591667,47.5 Z"
        fill="currentColor"
     />
</g>
```

Be sure to leave the other attributes alone such as fill since this will change the stroke of the path.

As others have suggested you can open an svg editor and create an svg with the letter A. Once you've done that it's just a matter of copying the path information into the `d` attribute.

Edit: The coordinates will need to line up, so you'll likely want to open the original file in inkscape and edit it there to make sure the coordinates line up properly.